# Let $k$ divides both $m+2n$ and $3m+4n$, prove $k$ also divides $m$ and $2n$

Tags: arithmetic

For any natural numbers $m$, $n$ and $k$, such that $k$ divides both $m + 2n$ and $3m+4n$, $k$ must be a common divisor of $m$ and $2n$.

I can confirm this postulation by putting trial and error values, say $m=10$, $n=5$,
$m + 2n = 20$ &
$3m + 4n = 50$.

$k$ can be $10$ which divides $m$ & $2n$.

But, is there a way to prove it more elegantly without using trial and error method?

Comment: Counterexample for the title: $m=1, n=1, k=3, m+2n = 3, 3m+4k = 15$. $k$ does not divide $m$ nor $2n$.

Comment: Corrected the title. Have some consideration, proofread your entire question

Comment: Consider $m = (3m+4n) - 2(m+2n)$.

Comment: peterwhy, in the first comment, it is 3m+4n and not 3m+4k. I can mark your second comment as answer, though...

Comment: @Madhavan are you familiar with the euclidean algorithm? I think that might help your understanding of this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If k|m+2n and k|3m+4n, then k|(3m+4n)-(m+2n), which means k|2m+2n. Subtracting k|m+2n from this result gives k|m. Subtracting this from k|m+2n results in k|2n. QED.

Comment: To make things faster, we can just say that k|(3m+4n)-2(m+2n).